# how to request a page in xml in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here is my code in a controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml  { render :xml => @menus }
end
```

when i type "http://192.168.210.136:3000" then it renders the html version.

but how do i request the xml version? i tried http://192.168.210.136:3000.xml and http://192.168.210.136:3000/index.xml with no luck.

thanks!

Comment: not tested guess: http://192.168.210.136:3000/.xml

Comment: What does your map.root look like in your routes file?

Comment: @gareth: root :to => 'firstpage#index'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to return XML - by default - in your root route, you might need to change your routes.rb to make it more explicit, like this (rails 3 example):

```
Sandbox::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  root :to => "static#index", :format => :xml
end
```

On rails 2.3.x you can pass your routes a defaults hash, like this:

```
map.connect 'photos/:id', :controller => 'photos',
                          :action => 'show',
                          :defaults => { :format => 'jpg' }
```

For more information regarding the rails router, please check the official Rails guides at:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

In the general case you add the `.xml` suffix to your URL to tell the Rails responder what you want. Your controller logic is the correct way to handle the incoming request.

E.g. A `User` `show` for ID=1 in XML would look like this:

> http://192.168.210.136:3000/users/1.xml

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you give http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#formats-and-respond-to a good read